# wordpress htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have a wordpress blog.

My question is. How to rewrite this url

```
www.1234.com/?s=&cp_state=city
```

On this

```
www.1234.com/city
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines to .htaccess file in root directory before WP directives, if any, or any other directive. Example:

```
#These are the 2 lines to add
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(city)/?$ ?s=&cp_state=$1 [L]
#End of added lines

# BEGIN WordPress - This is just an example, there might be more or different.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress - WP directives end here
```

The requested URL can be `www.1234.com/city` or `www.1234.com/city/` with or without `www`.

If necessary, in order to test redirection is working add something like this at the start of index.php:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['cp_state'] == 'city') {
    echo "cp_state = city<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

The string "cp_state = city" should be displayed.